# How can I display a selected list of checkboxes as another list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs on my page:

```
<div id="divOne">
   // List of checkboxes from my model
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />

<div id="divTwo">
   // I want to show a checkbox list that the user selected from divOne
</div>
```

How can I display a selected list of checkboxes as another list of checkboxes?

Comment: I was getting confused with using the model which I'm using to populate the first list with and trying to do the same with the second list.  Which doesn't appear to be a correct way to handle this.  It appears that I can populate the model and then post the second div back to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...just copy them from the other div.. `$("#divTwo").html($("#divOne").html());`

---

if you only want checked stuff..

```
var checkboxes = [];
$("#divOne").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $("#divTwo").append($(this).clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `.html()` and `.clone()`

```js
var div1 = $('#divOne'),
    div2 = $('#divTwo');

$('#btnAdd').on('click', function(){
    div2.html(
      div1.find('input:checked:enabled').clone() // grab the selected checkboxes
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">

   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />

<div id="divTwo">
   // I want to show a checkbox list that the user selected from divOne
</div>
```